# Tweet sheet ios5 presentModalViewController

Tags: ios, presentmodalviewcontroller, tweets

I am trying to integrate the tweet sheet from the twitter framework. I already got it working on my iPad but when I use the exact same code on my iPod I get a problem.

Everything is fine, I can open the tweet sheet I can type a tweet but when I want to cancel or send a tweet the buttons don't work?

I also noticed that I can still touch the screen behind the tweet sheet. Has anybody got an idea how to set the tweet sheet as the view to operate in? I thought presentModalViewController did that...

```
//Create the tweet sheet
TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

//Customize the tweet sheet here
//Add a tweet message
[tweetSheet setInitialText:@"text"];

//Add an image
NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
                  [NSString stringWithString: @"pngImage.png"] ];
UIImage* content = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

[tweetSheet addImage:content];


//Add a link
//Don't worry, Twitter will handle turning this into a t.co link
[tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"urlLink"]];


//Set a blocking handler for the tweet sheet
tweetSheet.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result){
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
};
//Show the tweet sheet!
[self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
```

Comment: After 2 days of searching I finally found the solution. Pretty stupid actually, but at least I found it :). In my xib file I used a window instead of a view.

Comment: You should answer your own question and mark it as the correct answer :)